# Что такое "баллы кандидата"?

Tags: поддержка, выборы

На странице [выдвижения кандидатов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) упоминаются "баллы кандидата". Что это такое и как они вычисляются?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Позвзоляют видеть результаты активности автора заявки в модераторы на Stack Overflow в удобном виде, чтобы не лезть в профиль и не искать.

Вычисляются из репутации и знаков различных категорий: знаки участника, редактора и модерации ([Полный список знаков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)). Если навести мышку на надпись со знаками, то появится подсказка о том, какие именно знаки были учтены при подсчете баллов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Участники при голосовании могут учитывать эти баллы на своё усмотрение.

Comment: Как получить это всплывающее окно? Мне кажется я просто энтузиаст.

Comment: @DiMithras _Если навести мышку на надпись со знаками ..._

Comment: Примерный список учитывающихся знаков (какого-то из знаков "модерации" не хватает): https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63323869#63323869

Comment: @aepot а, ну всё правильно, я просто энтузиаст, хотя изначально это юмор был

Comment: Нашлось, "спортивного поведения" не хватало в списке. Значит у меня 39.

Comment: @insolor чего не хватает?

Comment: @Danis "Инвестора", я слишком жадный)